# Has anyone gotten twilio authorization working?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

In the twilio documents for the Node SDK I came across a method for authorizing twilio requests:

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    twilio = require('twilio');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

// Twilio request authentication
app.post('/twiml', function(req, res) {
    if (twilio.validateExpressRequest(req, 'YOUR_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN')) {
        var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
        resp.say('express sez - hello twilio!');

        res.type('text/xml');
        res.send(resp.toString());
    }
    else {
        res.status(403).send('you are not twilio. Buzz off.');
    }
});

// Start an HTTP server with this Express app
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Yet when I run this the `twilio.validateExpressRequest` always returns false. Why is that? How do I get this example to work? Does anyone have experience with setting up security authorization in twilio?

Also I did change the twilio auth token to the proper one.

Comment: That looks correct. Is this running locally and using ngrok to tunnel? You may need to supply the URL as an options object. Check out the source code here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/master/lib/webhooks.js#L33-L55

Comment: I am deploying this on a server. Not sure what url I should provide it with; the docs use a heroku app in their example for the more general [validateRequest](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/2.1.0/index.html#validateRequest)

Comment: I'm also reading through this [detailed look at their security](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security#validating-requests) and it seems that there is no example for node, and it looks like the twilio library is missing a function called validator

Comment: Try `twilio.validateExpressRequest(res, 'YOUR_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN', { url: 'YOUR_HEROKU_URL' })`. It is a shame there's no Node example in the docs, I'll raise that with the team.